# binary search tree: NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, binary-search-tree, nameerror

I'm trying to build a binary search tree class and get a name error for:

```
children_num for this children_num == node.children_count()
```

This is the code that uses `children_num`:

```
def delete(self, value):
    '''delete node containing value'''
    node, parent = self.lookup(value)
    if node is not None:
        children_num == node.children_count()
    if children_num == 0:
        # first case- if there are no children you can just remove node
        if parent:
            if parent.leftChild is node:
                parent.leftChild = None
            else:
                parent.rightChild = None
            del node
        else:
            self.value = None
    elif children_num == 1:
        # case 2- if node has 1 child->replace node with its child
        if node.leftChild:
            n = node.leftChild
```

and this is the `children_count` function:

```
def children_count(self):
    # returns the number of children: 0 , 1 , 2
    total=0
    if self.leftChild:
        total += 1
    if self.rightChild:
        total += 1
    return total
```

I tried entering `children_num` in the `__init__` (`self.children_num= None`), making it a global var (`global children_num`) and define it as `children_num==0`, none of these worked.

Comment: children_num == node.children_count() should be children_num = node.children_count() i.e. = not ==

Comment: Thank's, once I did it I got : AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'children_count'. I
 don't get it, the function returns int.

Comment: Can you provide the exact details of the error. Line number is it in the above code or some other code thats not posted here?

Comment: No idea how that last edit approved but tried to fix formatting etc. Feel free to rollback/edit again if anything is wrong.

Comment: It's in the same line as before: children_num == node.children_count()

Comment: I approved the edit, it  was mostly grammer :)

Comment: According to your error, your `self.lookup` returns an integer value for `node`. You should check there or paste it here.

Comment: it should return a int object, i tried:

    node , parent = str(self.lookup(value))    

i got a : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) for this line

Comment: int doesn't have children_count. Your class instance has that method. So you need to use `your_class_instance_name.children_count()` instead of `integer.children_count()`

Comment: That solved it, thank you :) it clarified a few thing for me